# Installing Cordova - npm ERR! registry error parsing json

Tags: json, cordova, npm

I am trying to install Cordova, but always getting this ERROR

> npm ERR! registry error parsing json

Comment: Almost zero context here, so it's extremely difficult to determine your issue. If a `npm-debug.log` is generated (which it should be on-error), you should upload it as [gist](https://gist.github.com/) and post the link here so we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Because you forgot sudo.

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

Answer (score 0):

try to upgrade ur npm & node.js:

1. npm install -g npm
2. npm install -g n
3. n stable